# UPDATE - SQL Server : error converting data type varchar to int

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is causing an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int

This is the code where I explicitly convert ID to int and I'm **not getting error**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(int, f.ID) AS GroupID, 
    CONVERT(int, i.ID) AS ItemID,
    GETDATE() AS ModifiedDate,
    N'StageSyncImp' AS ModifiedBy
FROM 
    XY...
```

But when I do this with exactly **the same data as a source**:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.test (GroupID, ItemID, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CONVERT(int, f.ID) AS GroupID, 
        CONVERT(int, i.ID) AS ItemID,
        GETDATE() AS ModifiedDate,
        N'StageSyncImp' AS ModifiedBy
    FROM 
        XY...
```

I'm getting that conversion error:

[image]

Here is the `dbo.Test` table structure:

[image]

**Question:** Why I'm not getting errors when converting data, but when I'm converting same data and inserting them to the table, there is an error?

Comment: We can't run your query, so we don't why you're getting the error. Perhaps it's a poorly written trigger.

Comment: Though, if `GroupID` and `ItemID` are `int` columns, why are you `CONVERT`ing them to a `decimal(10,4)` in your `SELECT`? This is especially confusing when they're foreign keys.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code. Questionedited and int added.

Comment: Are you sure it's a conversion error and not a constraint violation?

Comment: can f.ID have non-int values? For example you have a WHERE that filters them out

Comment: What are the data types of `f.ID` and `i.ID`? As you are `CONVERT`ing them then presumably they *aren't* an `int`. Are you using a `varchar` to store numerical data? If so, there's your problem. If you provide a [mre] you'll probably find the problem (which is why we ask to create one before asking).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: We need to see the rest of the query, to explain where f.ID and i.ID came from. We also need to see the column definition for those fields along with some sample data.

Comment: I'm confused. CONVERT does not convert?
Even if `f.ID` and `i.ID` were not an integer, why I'm not getting converting errors in the first example?
Using CONVERT I'm preparing data to fit with data types in the target table.

Comment: `CONVERT` does *convert*, @LiborP , but it *can't* convert an invalid value. What would you expect `CONVERT(int,'I like turtles')` to return? What "`int`" value is `'I like turtles'`?

Comment: @ThomA I expect to get same error in first example as I'm getting in second one.

Comment: Exactly, so why are you surprised that `CONVERT` can't convert your data when it has bad data in the column(s)?

Comment: What is `FROM XY` here what are you selecting from?

Answer (score 1):

This is **likely** (we can't see enough of the code or data to be sure) a common issue with database order of operations. You have varchar columns backing `f.ID` and `i.ID` that have mixed data in them: some values can convert to int, but some cannot. You are then using a WHERE clause or JOIN condition to limit the query to only include values that do convert safely to int.

The problem is databases do not and will NEVER promise to use the order of operations you expect. There are many cases where the database will deem it more efficient to do the data projections (ie: CONVERT() calls) *earlier*, and the filtering operations *later*. And when this happens there is very little you can do to convince the database it needs to change this.

Instead, use the [TRY_CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function that will give a NULL result for the invalid rows without failing the whole query. Or, even better, define the schema in a way that doesn't mix data types.

Comment: `f.ID` and `i.ID` are simple IDs in tables (Primary key, auto increase, int, not null), these data cannot be varchar.

Comment: @LiborP Then why even call the `CONVERT()` function, if they are _already_ integers?

Comment: Just to be sure and avoid conversations about issues with IDs and their previous type.

Comment: What previous type? It's an **int** column. _There can't be anything there but int values._

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a **Trigger** on `dbo.Test`.

Comment: Showing the trigger in the question, and explaining what went wrong in the answer, might be of help

Comment: I'm sorry, cannot show you anything, it's confidential. It's also part of complex logic with thousands of lines. 
I was just asking about possible reasons of the problem.
And the reason was, that there are some triggers which working with other data and tables when inserting or updating to `dbo.Test`.
My question was to find direction, not to have solution that I have copy. ;-)